# How to overlook zero fields in MATLAB-plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an 600*2 array in MATLAB lets call it **`tmp`**
what in one point starts to be

```
-22222    0
-22222    0
-22222    0
-22222    0
```

My code is

```
plot(tmp(:,2),tmp(:,1))
```

How can i make it ignore rows that contain 0?

Answer (score 0):

First you could remove the zero rows like this:

```
tmp(tmp == 0) = [];
```

then `plot(tmp(:,2),tmp(:,1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new matrix with only the nonzero elements of `tmp`:

```
  nonzero_rows = find(tmp(:,2) ~= 0);
  tmp2 = tmp(nonzero_rows,;);
```

Then plot `tmp2` instead of `tmp`

Comment: No need to `use` find. Use logical indexing directly: `nonzero_rows = tmp(:,2)~=0; tmp2 = tmp(nonzero_rows,:);`